# How to set an OnTouchListener to a string

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I want to highlight text and then drag and drop it to a specific area. I know how basic drag and drop works and how to get the selected area to a `String`.

But I don't know how to to attach a `setOnClickListener` on a `String`? Anyone have any idea or is that a total wrong approach?

The `string` is in an `editView`

```
 et    =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
       int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();

       test = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

Comment: Where is your String ? On a textView?

Comment: I dont think that there is any way to show the string in android without using any view

Comment: what do you mean a string? u mean a textView ?

Comment: the string is in an editText

Comment: add TextWachter or clicklistener to edit text

Comment: Maybe this can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363484/how-can-i-have-edittext-with-clickable-spannables-and-still-selectable-by-longcl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters pointed out, you can not set a a touch listener on a `String`, you have to do it on your `EditText`. You would do something like this:

```
et.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            et.setFocusable(true);
            et.requestFocus();
            // Do what you want 

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Do what you want 
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

But still, I do not understand why do you want to use a `OnTouchListener` and not a `OnDragListener`, which seems to serve your purpose better...

Comment: valid point with ondraglistener. The problem is, I only want to drag the selected/highlighted text (which is "test") and not the whole EditText.